# Javascript : wait for for loop to finish before executing next loop

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have a scenario where I have to delete attachments first and then upload new attachments. Here is my code:

```
        var programs = this.UploadModel.getProperty("/programs/items"); 

        //Delete files first
        for(var i=0; i<filesToDelete.length; i++){
            oThis._callAttachmentWS("DELETE", proj, filesToDelete[i]);
        }

        //Then save new files   
        for(var i=0; i<programs.length; i++){
            oThis._callAttachmentWS("SAVE", proj, programs[i]);
        }
```

How do I make the second for loop wait for the first loop to finish?

Comment: Does `oThis._callAttachmentWS` return a Promise?

Comment: no it does not, it calls a web service and the return is true or false

Comment: If the function simply queues up requests that finish whenever, you cannot await the first loop. Where's the function coming from? Can you change it? Does it support a callback parameter?

Comment: the function is coming from another controller.  It can be changed. Since it's an ajax call, then callback back is most likely supported

Comment: if it's an ajax call, and you can do callbacks - perhaps look at using Promises - it'll make the rest of the code far easier to work with (they're just glorified callbacks anyway)

Comment: It's `_callAttachmentWS` that needs to be updated. It should build an array of API calls, which you can use something like [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) on, and you can then [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) the promise returned from the controller from within your main function. So you can `await` the first update, and then do the second one.

Comment: Provide the (potentially simplified) code for `_callAttachmentWS`, so we can explain what to change.

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP within the comments states ...

> *"... it calls a web service and the return is true or false"*

> *"... the function is coming from another controller. It can be changed. Since it's an ajax call, then callback back is most likely supported"*

... and looking at how ...

```
oThis._callAttachmentWS("DELETE", proj, filesToDelete[i]);
```

... respectively ...

```
oThis._callAttachmentWS("SAVE", proj, programs[i]);
```

... are being used, one could assume the `_callAttachmentWS` method returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) are two methods each operating upon the states of a list of promises and returning a promise itself.

The next provided example code utilizes the latter method. The implementation also mocks the behavior of an asynchronous (promise returning) `_callAttachmentWS` method. There are promise returning helper functions for the also mocked file save/delete tasks. The main task, called `handleFileDeleteAndFileSave`, shows a possible solution of how one could handle the promise chain(s) ...

```js
function callAttachmentWS(action, project, fileName) {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {

        // file deletion completed.
        resolve({ action, fileName });

      }, 3000);
    }
  );
}
// var programs = this.UploadModel.getProperty("/programs/items");

// //Delete files first
// for(var i=0; i<filesToDelete.length; i++){
//     oThis._callAttachmentWS("DELETE", proj, filesToDelete[i]);
// }
// 
// //Then save new files   
// for(var i=0; i<programs.length; i++){
//     oThis._callAttachmentWS("SAVE", proj, programs[i]);
// }

function triggerFileActions(action, fileList) {
  console.log(`+++ trigger ${ action.toLowerCase() } files +++`);

  // returns an array of promises.
  return fileList.map(fileName =>
    /*oThis._*/callAttachmentWS(action, 'my-project-name', fileName)
  )
}

function deleteFiles(fileList) {
  // returns a promise.
  return Promise.allSettled(triggerFileActions('DELETE', fileList));
}
function saveFiles(fileList) {
  // returns a promise.
  return Promise.allSettled(triggerFileActions('SAVE', fileList));
}

function handleFileDeleteAndFileSave(deleteList, saveList) {
  // returns a promise.
  return deleteFiles(

    deleteList

  ).then(deleteResultList => {

    deleteResultList.forEach(result => console.log(result));
    console.log('... delete files finished ...');

  }).then(() => {
    // returns a promise.
    return saveFiles(

      saveList

    ).then(saveResultList => {

      saveResultList.forEach(result => console.log(result));
      console.log('... save files finished ...');

    }).then(() => '+++ handleFileDeleteAndFileSave is settled +++');
  });
}

const filesToDelete = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
const programs = ['bizz', 'buzz'];

handleFileDeleteAndFileSave(
  filesToDelete,
  programs,  
)
.then(status => console.log(status));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

As the above code shows, the properly timed handling of file delete/save is based on nested promise chains. In order to free the programmers' minds from writing and maintaining such structures the [`async ... await` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) was introduced.

The next code example repeats the above code block, just in a more imperative programming style ...

```js
async function callAttachmentWS(action, project, fileName) {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {

        // file deletion completed.
        resolve({ action, fileName });

      }, 3000);
    }
  );
}

function triggerFileActions(action, fileList) {
  console.log(`+++ trigger ${ action.toLowerCase() } files +++`);

  // returns an array of promises.
  return fileList.map(fileName =>
    callAttachmentWS(action, 'my-project-name', fileName)
  )
}

async function deleteFiles(fileList) {
  // returns a promise.
  return Promise.allSettled(triggerFileActions('DELETE', fileList));
}
async function saveFiles(fileList) {
  // returns a promise.
  return Promise.allSettled(triggerFileActions('SAVE', fileList));
}

async function handleFileDeleteAndFileSave(deleteList, saveList) {
  // handles promises (async functions) via `await` syntax,
  // thus it makes it an async function too
  // which (implicitly) returns a promise.
  const deleteResultList = await deleteFiles(deleteList);

  deleteResultList.forEach(result => console.log(result));
  console.log('... delete files finished ...');

  const saveResultList = await saveFiles(saveList);

  saveResultList.forEach(result => console.log(result));
  console.log('... save files finished ...');

  return '+++ handleFileDeleteAndFileSave is settled +++';
}

const filesToDelete = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
const programs = ['bizz', 'buzz'];

(async function () {
  const status =
    await handleFileDeleteAndFileSave(filesToDelete, programs);

  console.log(status);
}());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use async/await.
[Here is more about them](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).